# Cannot do apt-get upgrade

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

I am getting below error when running apt-get update, how to fix?

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-base' missing; assuming package has no files 
currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-libc-dev:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'ncurses-base' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: restore from most recent working backup - I'm assuming you are running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: What if there is no backup?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

Comment: It doesn't seem to have done anything

Comment: "What if there is no backup?" - you have learned a valuable lesson. Try `sudo apt-get clean` but I don't hold great hopes.

Comment: Use `apt` - "apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

Comment: Which version of Raspian (is it old)? Backup your data first before continuing. Does `apt-get install --reinstall linux-base` and `apt-get install --reinstall linux-libc-dev:armhf` solve your problem? (also for `ncurses`)